# Centering a canvas on a given point

Tags: c#, .net, canvas, point

I am trying to center a rectangle on a point and can't figure out the math needed to do it.

The context this is being used in is a form which paints a bitmap and allows the user to zoom in at a specified point, and pan/scroll while zoomed in.

Here is my code which current works for centering the CanvasBounds on the middle of the ClientRectangle:

```
    private void UpdateCanvas()
    {
        int canvasWidth = (int)(_bitmap.Width * _zoomRatio);
        int canvasHeight = (int)(_bitmap.Height * _zoomRatio);

        Point canvasLocation = new Point((ClientRectangle.Width - canvasWidth) / 2, (ClientRectangle.Height - canvasHeight) / 2);

        CanvasBounds = new Rectangle(canvasLocation, new Size(canvasWidth, canvasHeight));
    }
```

_zoomRatio is the zoom which adjusts the size of the canvas.  1.0 would be 100%, 2.0 is 200%, etc.

Basically instead I want to feed this function a point taken by mouse input, and use that point as the center for the canvasBounds rectangle.  Then when the user manipulates the horizontal and vertical scroll bars, it can change the _centerPoint and update the CanvasBounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to just offset your "point" with your canvas size:

```
private void UpdateCanvas(Point mousePoint)
{
  int canvasWidth = (int)(_bitmap.Width * _zoomRatio);
  int canvasHeight = (int)(_bitmap.Height * _zoomRatio);
  int canvasX = (mousePoint.X - (canvasWidth / 2));
  int canvasY = (mousePoint.Y - (canvasHeight / 2));
  CanvasBounds = new Rectangle(canvasX, canvasY, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
}
```

If that's not what you are looking for, maybe edit your post with a simple screen shot.